# Django. Can't get absolute url

Tags: django, django-urls

I need a link to supplier_data for logged in supplier. Can't get it with any method. I get empty element.
Model:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.OneToOneField(User, max_length=120, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField('Currency', max_length=4)
    legal_form = models.CharField('Legal form', max_length=100, choices=legal_form_options, default='Sole proprietorship')
    accounting_standards = models.CharField('Accounting standards', max_length=100)
    owner_structure = models.CharField('Owner structure', max_length=100)
    industry_sector = models.CharField('Industry sector', max_length=100, choices=industry_sector_options, default='Advertising')  
    date_of_establishment = models.DateField('Date of establishment', default=date.today)
    start_up = models.CharField('Start-up', choices=start_up_options, default='No', max_length=4)
    email_address = models.EmailField('Email address')
    web = models.URLField('Website address')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('supplier_data', args=[self.id])
```

View:

```
def all_suppliers(request):
    supplier_list = Supplier.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'all_suppliers.html',{'supplier_list': supplier_list})

def supplier_data(request, id): 
    supplier_list = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'all_suppliers.html',{'supplier_list': supplier_list})
```

Url:

```
    path('supplier_data/<int:id>', views.supplier_data, name="supplier_data"),
```

Html:

```
        {% for supplier in supplier_list %}
        <a id=link href="{% url 'supplier_data' supplier.id %}">Supplier data</a>
        {%endfor%}
```

I spent about one week trying with get_absolute_url method and without it... many things...
Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: what is exactly not working? which element is empty?

Comment: <a id=link href="{% url 'supplier_data' supplier.id %}">Supplier data</a> is not rendering at all. Link appears when I remove loop and put href="/supplier_data", but it has to end with /id

Comment: Does your `supplier_list` have any suppliers? Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for spaces in tags {% endfor %} and remove id as it must be unique and a string like id="link1" but makes no sense here:

```
{% for supplier in supplier_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'supplier_data' supplier.id %}">Supplier data</a>
{% endfor %}
```

and make sure that supplier_list is not empty (no objects in database created yet) e.g by placing it before the loop for debugging like:

```
xxx{{supplier_list}}xxx
{% for .... %}
```

xxx just to make an empty string visible.

if you need a unique id for some reason you can create it using the forloop counter:

```
id = "link{{forloop.counter}}"
```

no spaces in {{template_variable}} !

Comment: {{supplier_list}} renders suppliers in one app, but does not in others, even if def all_suppliers is in another views. I'll try with putting all things to one app.